# Read first two elements from multiple files C++

Tags: c++, matrix, multiple-columns

I have a 4*4 matrix in 4 files. I need to read the first two elements from each files and display it in a column. Here is an example:

```
File 1        File 2        File 3       File 4
1 2 3 4       2 3 4 5       3 5 8 9      1 4 6 9
3 4 4 5       3 4 5 6       6 7 9 2      6 0 8 6
1 2 4 5       4 5 6 6       8 7 6 5      4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4       4 4 7 9       3 4 5 6      5 6 7 9
```

I need to display first row 2 column elements from File 1, first row 2 column elements from file 2 and so on:

```
1 + 2 (File 1, 1st row 2 elements)
2 + 3 (File 2, 1st row 2 elements)
3 + 5 (File 3, 1st row 2 elements)
1 + 4 (File 4, 1st row 2 elements)
3 + 4 (file 1, 2nd row 2 elements)
3 + 4 (file 2, 2nd row 2 elements)
6 + 7 (File 3, 2nd row 2 elements)
```

and so on..

```
//std::fstream infile;
string st1 = "file_";
string st2 = ".txt";
string st3 = "_";
string filename;
string mystring;
float fading[16][16];


         for( int row = 0 ; row < 5 ; ++row)
        {
         for( int column = 0 ; column < 5 ; ++column)
          {

            for ( int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
            {
              for(int j = 1; j < 3 ;j++)
              {
                stringstream ss, ss1;
                ss << i;
                ss1 << j;
                filename = st1 + ss.str() + st3 + ss1.str() + st2;
                std::fstream infile;
                infile.open(filename.c_str());
                if(infile.is_open())
                {
                infile >> fading[row][column];
                cout << "fading[" << row << "][" << column << "] " << fading[row][column] << std::endl;
                }
                else
                    std::cout << " file " << filename << " not open" << std::endl;
                infile.close();
               }
            }
          }
        }
}
```

I am not able to get the first row two elements from each file into a loop. Each time the file closes, the program starts from the 1 row of the first file again.

Comment: Why not read all the elements you need from each file, store them as you go and then do your computation?

Comment: Create for 4 `ifstream` variables and do not close them until the end of the program.

Comment: If you close and open a file, you will again read from the first

Comment: yeah.. I put the files before the loop, but no success in reading the first row 2 elements from each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not read the entire matrices into memory buffers and fetch the fields you need from there? If it's really only four files with 16 entries each, that's not too expensive and you don't have the hassle of reading around in your file.

Answer (score 0):

I guess You want to open the file before the loop , That will keep data pointers inside the file to the point where it last read .